# Add from and subject when sending mail using jobs and markdown

Tags: email, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am trying to change 'myemail@gmail.com' address to something like: no-reply@gmail.com and trying to add a custom address but I am unable to get it to work.

Which file do I add the **subject** and **from**?

## my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Custom App Name"
```

## controller code

```
dispatch(new JblockedUser($user));
```

## jobs file

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

use Mail;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Mail\BlockedUser;

class JblockedUser implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $email = new BlockedUser($this->user);
        Mail::to('example@gmail.com')->queue($email);
    }
}
```

## mail file

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class BlockedUser extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.newsletter');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `from` and `subject` in your mailable build method. By default if no `from` address is provided, then laravel uses the global from address and name set in the config file. The default subject will be built using your mailable class name. In your case `Blocked User` would be the subject.

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('no-reply@example.com')
        ->subject('Newsletter!!!')
        ->markdown('emails.newsletter');
}
```

Or if you need to specify the email and name.

```
public function build()
{
    $from = [
        'address' => 'no-reply@example.com',
        'name' => 'Custom App Name'
    ];

    return $this->from($from)
        ->subject('Newsletter!!!')
        ->markdown('emails.newsletter');
}
```

You might want to run `php artisan config:clear` in case your .env file changes aren't reflecting.

Comment: I am accepting the answer but there was one more issue that was causing from picking the values from .env file. If anyone using smtp.gmail.com then whatsoever you provide "from recipient" to be it will fall back to original one until and unless it is added to google account by going to settings and configuring for example : no-reply@example.com and now it works smoothly.